# Handling requests with multiple threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have class `Sender` that has a function `add_task(task)` to add the task to the thread pool. The task needs to be handled by one of the 10 worker threads. Each thread has to have a unique information, say their own `address` (needs to be loaded form the config file) to do the job.

Currently I was thinking of using `ThreadPoolExecutor` & `threading.Local` to store `address` for each worker thread. Something like this:

```
class Sender:
  # addresses of len 10
  def __init__(self, addresses):
    self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10, initializer=initialize, initargs=(addresses))

  def add_task(task):
    fut = self.executor.submit(task)
    fut.add_done_callback(dummy_callback)

def initialize(addresses):|
  # ... thread name is <pool prefix>_i
  retrieve that i 
  data = threading.Local()
  data.address = addresses[i]

def task():
  # do something with data.address
  print(data.address)

def dummy_callback():
  pass
```

I am not sure if I am going in the right direction. Could you give any hints on that?

Comment: Thread pools can recycle threads, and the index may not be what you expect always like 1-10 or 0-9. Ideally, you should  not associate thread meta data with application data. Instead, you can always pass the information needed in the executable task you submit.

Comment: But I still need each worker thread to have their own unique variables (in this case `address`). Of course, I can have a lock & counter and assign indices to those worker threads when they are first time handling the task, but I was just thinking there might be an easier solution.

Comment: The default behavior of threadpool may not suit your need. If you think, you need only fixed number of threads to work with, then you can ignore threadpool. Or go with some customized implementation, an example like this https://gist.github.com/tliron/81dd915166b0bfc64be08b4f8e22c835